# Python. Условие по полю Дата (Timestamp) меньше или равно

Tags: python, datetime

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Пишу функцию, которая возвращает бинарный признак 1 или 0 - сразу по нескольким условиям, которые должны быть True, как говориться.

```
def ak(df3):
if df3['agr_count'] > 0 and df3['akt_count'] > 0 \
         and (df3['akt_dt_max'] + timedelta(days=365) \
         and (df3['akt_dt_max'] < '2023-05-22')):
    val = 1
else :
    val = 0
return val
```

Затем создаю в Датафрейме столбец

```
df3['no_akt_to_more_1_year'] = df3.apply(ak, axis=1)
```

Если запустить функцию, такую как я написал - выдает ошибку:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'str'
```

Но, если из функции убрать последнее условие `(df3['akt_dt_max'] < '2023-05-22')` или поменять его на `(df3['akt_dt_max'] == '2023-05-22')` то код отрабатывает без проблем.

При этом я точно знаю, что в датафрейме есть даты ранее 2023-05-22.
И если прописываю аналогичное условие на импортированном датасете в MS Power BI - создаю столбец в таблице:  `Нет акта больше года = if(_table[agr_count]>0 && _table[akt_count]>0 && (_table[akt_dt_max]+365)<=date(2023,5,22),1,0)` тоже все срабатывает, столбец создается с бинарным признаком 1 и 0, как и положено.

Как мне все таки написать такое условие в Python?

Comment: `not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'str'` ­— вы пытаетесь сравнить зелёное с тёплым. приведите оба сравниваемых значения к одному типу — либо `Timestamp`, либо `str`

Comment: а что вы хотели сделать вот этим: `and (df3['akt_dt_max'] + timedelta(days=365) `?

Comment: @strawdog
существуют некоторые акты выполненных работ, которые появляются с интревалом раз в 1 год, но бывает так, что их нет больше 1 года - чтобы их вычислить я добавляю к полю с датами актов 1 год, но при этом меньше 22 мая 2023. Например, предыдущий акт был 22 марта 2022 года, следующий акт должен быть ровно через год 22 марта 2023 года - если акта нет то 1, если есть то 0.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin
Спасибо!!! Помогло!! я сделал вот так: `stamp = pd.Timestamp('2023-05-22 00:00:00')` а условия написал так: `(df3['akt_dt_max'] < stamp)` и все сработало! Дай Бог Вам здоровья крепкого, Александр!

Comment: ну это не тема текущего вопроса, конечно, но вся ваша конструкция if очень странно выглядит.: `(df3['akt_dt_max'] + timedelta(days=365)  and (df3['akt_dt_max'] < '2023-05-22'))`.  вы прям словами ее разъясните.

Comment: @strawdog спасибо! Здесь у меня тоже оказалась ошибка, надо было так: `(df3['akt_dt_max'] + timedelta(days=365) <= stamp)`